# Android Studio 3.1 - Layout Editor Preview - Screen Capture Missing

Tags: android, screen-capture, android-studio-3.1, graphical-layout-editor, xml-editor

I just upgraded to Android Studio 3.1 Stable Version and found that the feature to save a screen capture of the layout preview in the Graphical Layout Editor is missing. This feature was there in Android Studio 3.0.1. You would right click on the preview and it would take a screenshot of it. I need it to make graphics of the Pixel 2 XL and shouldn't have to start my emulator for just that.

What happened to it? How do I turn it on again?

Answer (score -2):

**Try :**

- In Android Studio, select <kbd>View</kbd> > Tool <kbd>Windows</kbd> > <kbd>Logcat</kbd> to **open Logcat**.
- **Select the device and a process** from the drop-down at the top of the window.
- **Click Screen Capture** on the left side of the window.

[image]

Reference : [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-screenshot.html)

Comment: This is for taking a screenshot of the device/emulator when testing. My device screen ratio isn't 2880x1440 like the Pixel 2 XL. And my emulator is too expensive on my RAM. It won't start.

Comment: @SynerFlow the functionality is same. but they removed from preview to real device. In new android studio no option for taking ss of preview

Comment: @Vishwa Dave Even though it's the same result, There is a substantial difference in the time and effort it takes to capture a few simple screenshots. What a stupid move by the Android Studio team.

Comment: @SynerFlow What we can do :D It is new android studio new features :P

Comment: I've spent 1 hour googling trying to find where it is... but as other comments said, this is stupid but what can we do? Just use all our PC resources to take a simple screenshot... or use a real device that's not always available...

Comment: @SynerFlow, it was a stupid move to remove screenshot from layout preview. I wasted 30+ mins googling and trying to find where it was hidden (layout preview screenshot) coz i can swear i used it before.